# Is there any way to convert Microsoft word document to notepad file .txt formate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, ms-word, office-interop

I try this code

```
string[] ext = att.Name.Split('.');
string file = ext[0].ToString();
object Target = file + ".txt";
object nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

Application.Documents.Open(ref FileName, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref value, ref value, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
object format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatUnicodeText;

Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref Target, ref format,
                        ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                        ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                        ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                        ref Unknown, ref Unknown, ref Unknown,
                        ref Unknown, ref Unknown);
Application.Visible = false;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc1 = Application.ActiveDocument;
string strNewDocText1 = oDoc1.Content.Text;
```

But in strNewDocText1 get output including bullets and extra word formate

I want to simple plain-text format of my word document into text documnt.

Comment: You cannot safely use the Office APIs from a service program like ASP.NET. They were designed for desktop use only.

Comment: See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you took this example from here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5273/How-to-convert-DOC-into-other-formats-using-C

So basically you have a RTF, which must be convert to plain text. Here is an example

Simplest approach is just to add reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll.

```
System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();

string richText = text// The rich text (with bullets and so on.)
rtBox.Rtf = richText ;
string plainText = rtBox.Text;

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"output.txt", plainText);
```

Comment: But my application not is not desktop application

Comment: This does not mean that you cant add reference to that asembly. Thats fastest and simplest solution.

Comment: He not has not available not RichTextBox... at the moment

Comment: @Mare Infinitus what you say i can't get it?

Comment: Well i see no problem adding reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll, but if you do not want to add reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll. You should write a lot :) this article may help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter

Comment: i added System.Windows.Forms.dll. @Nas

Comment: @Nas when i run this code i get error `file format not vaild`

Comment: On which line the exception is thrown?

Comment: `rtBox.Rtf = richText ;` when it takes string richtext value

Comment: You should debug and see what is causing that problem. You may also put the string which is causing the exception to be able to further help you. Also is it doc or docx document?

Comment: Both doc and docx document @Nas

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13158/discussion-between-krunal-mevada-and-nas)

Comment: @Nas i not get word inside texttool in word document. any idea about that.